# use just one where for all UNION ALL selects

Tags: mysql

I have this select and I want to optimize it.

I was wondering if I could use for all this `UNION ALL` just one `where` instead of repeat this all the time making mysql scan table 4 times instead of just 1

```
select id from sells
where user_id in (select fv from favorite where user =?)
union all
select id from likes
where user_id in (select fv from favorite where user =?)
union all
select id from favorites
where user_id in (select fv from favorite where user =?)
union all
select id from comments
where user_id in (select fv from favorite where user =?)
```

is it possible? how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
select user_id
from (select user_id from sells union all
      select user_id from likes union all
      select user_id from favorites union all
      select user_id from comments
     ) x
where user_id in (select fv from favirote where user = ?);
```

However, I would discourage this because of performance.  There are two hits.  First, the subquery is materialized, which slows down processing.  More importantly, the subqueries do not take advantage of indexes, further slowing down the query.

Your version is probably the most reasonable, assuming that you have proper indexes (on all the `user_id` columns and `fv`).

Also, if you don't want duplicates, use `union` instead of `union all`.  I usually advocate `union all`, but this seems to be a case where duplicate removal is warranted.

Probably the most performant approach is this:

```
select f.fv
from favorites f
where f.user = ? and
      (exists (select 1 from sells s where s.user_id = f.fv) or
       exists (select 1 from likes l where l.user_id = f.fv) or
       exists (select 1 from favorites f where s.user_id = f.fv) or
       exists (select 1 from comments c where s.user_id = c.fv) 
      );
```

This can make use of indexes and doesn't require additional overhead.

Comment: oh, so I should keep using my select version? I thought just one where would be much faster! thank you very much!

Comment: @Livia . . The fastest method should be the last, but you need an index on `favorites(user, fv)` in addition to indexes on the other tables.

Comment: thank you! indeed, those tables can have each million of rows, so I must use the fastest one! thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

```
select id,user_id from(
    select id,user_id from sells
    union all
    select id,user_id from likes
    union all
    select id,user_id from favorites
    union all
    select id,user_id from comments
) as t
where user_id in (select fv from favorite where user =?)
```

Comment: thank you! I think your select is much faster than mine, isnt it?